# JavaFX CSS "Resource not found"

Tags: java, css, javafx, classpath

When I attempted to change the folder where my css files were located, I got this error:

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged Resource "file:/C:/[path-to-project]/Test/resources/css/main.css" not found.
```

I copied the URL and pasted it into the file manager and it opened the file, so I know it exists.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    primaryStage.setTitle("New Window");

    Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane(), 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    URL css = new URL("file:///" + 
            new File("resources/css").getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/") + 
            "/main.css");
    scene.getStylesheets().clear();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(css.toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This is my eclipse project layout [[also as an image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElKi6.png):

```
Test
├───src
│   └───com
│       └───Client.java
├───JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]
└───resources
    └───css
        └───main.css
```

I have tried:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/resources/css/main.css")); 
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("resources/css/main.css"));
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("../resources/css/main.css"));
```

I also tried using fxml to add the css files trying:

```
stylesheets="@../resources/css/main.css"
stylesheets="@/resouces/css/main.css"
stylesheets="@resources/css/main.css
```

Comment: You should add your `resources` path to your classpath in Eclipse.

Comment: old but for the ocassional reader: For Jigsaw there is a FIXME note in the javafx source: "/ FIXME: JIGSAW -- use Class.getResourceAsStream if resource is in a module". Lets hope they fix that soon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put your `main.css` file inside `resources/com` directory (so `resources` + package of the class loading it) and then you can use a simple (assuming your class is named `Client` and it is in the `com` package):

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(Client.class.getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());
```